# phantomjs screenshots differs on different machines

Tags: phantomjs, vaadin

I have created an integration test on my local developer machine.
With VaadinTestBench I have created a screenshot that should be used as a reference screenshot.
After uploading the reference screenshot to svn and using jenkins to verify the build I get a slightly different image and therefore the test fails.

It seems that the fonts are different, but I have installed the same fonts and the website specifies the font to use.
But of course I cannot verify that exactly the same fonts are used.

Here is a sample pic (please ignore the purple border):
http://picpaste.com/phantomJS.jpg

Do you have an idea how to make the screenshots be identical?

Thank you
Tobias

Comment: Why can you of course NOT verify what font's are used? Right click on the object and then look what font is specified and if all the font resources are loaded/found on the server. Are the screenshots from the same machine? Could also be a resolution or font hinting difference

Comment: As phantomJS and therefore the jenkins server is also, I cannot verify this via a simple right click.
The screenshots are from different machines: Top: my local dev machine, bottom: jenkins server.

Comment: So it could very well be some different screen resolution, font hinting etc. Is there perhaps a way to "fuzzy-match" the two images instead of a 100% perfect pixel match?

Comment: There is.
But as the whole website is shifted by ~5-10px due to the different font rendering I do not know if this works.
But I can try it.

Comment: Apparently they have removed this option.
But I narrowed down the issue to plain phantomjs: I have created a html page with just text forced to font "arial". But there is still a difference in rendering on both machines.

Comment: Perhaps use the screenshots from phantomJS as "reference" instead?

Comment: This is what I do currently.
First I let phantomJS create a reference screenshot and then compare this in every integration test cycle. But these reference images are different for each machine. So for 4 devs and 1 jenkins you would have 5 folders with nearly the same images. But everyone has to maintain his own images.

Comment: I have created an issue regarding this: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13381